# Get block content from a template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I' ve a template file containing several blocks, but how can i get the content of one of the blocks? For instance:

```
{% extends "base.txt" %}
{% block subject %}Sub1{% endblock %}
{% block body %}Bod1{% endblock %}
```

. Is there any way to get only the content of the subject block?

Comment: What do you mean, "get the content"? Get it where?

Comment: I edited my question. So i' d like to render the template, and i' d like to have the content of the subject block, so the result will be only ''Sub1'' .

Comment: That still doesn't make much sense... have it where? what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Well, i' ve templates, which can be rendered, and i' d like to get only the content of a particular block. I' m not talking about views, only pure django. Let' s have it in a management command.

Comment: You can extract it into a template file of its own, and use `{% include %}` to include the subject in there.

Comment: @KarthikRavindra: now i c i wasn' t clear. I don' t want to have the content in / from a different template, but from the backend (for instance in the views.py or in a management command).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i get it correctly this should do the trick:

[Django-render-block](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-render-block/)

> Render the content of a specific block tag from a Django template. Works for
>   arbitrary template inheritance, even if a block is defined in the child template
>   but not in the parent. Generally it works like `render_to_string` from Django,
>   but allows you to specify a block to render.